# Break for loop with function?

Tags: c++

```
void fbreak(int i){
   if(5==i)
      break;
}
void main(){
   for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
      fbreak(i);
   }
}
```

I want to function fbreak break for loop. But it seems that my code does not work.

Comment: You can't do it this way.

Comment: How I can break that loop with function? :(

Comment: @user3837245 You can't. Use a `#define` macro instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact what you are trying to do is to implement stadard algorithm `std::find` (or `std::find_if`) declared in header `<algorithm>`

You could write your program the following way

```
bool fbreak( int i )
{
   return i == 6;
}

int main()
{
   int i = 0;

   while ( i < 10 && !fbreak( i ) ) i++;
}
```

Take into account that function main shall have return type `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You actually can't do so from the function scope, but what you easily can do is

```
bool fbreak(int i){
   return (5==i);
}
int main(){
   for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
      if(fbreak(i)) break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple modification to you code will be

```
void fbreak(int *i){
   if(5== *i)
      *i = 10;
}
void main(){
   for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
      fbreak(&i);
   }
}
```

This will increase the value of i to 10, that will cause the loop to break

Comment: This calls unwanted side effects certainly!

Comment: You're changing `i`?? Isn't that a side effect compared to the other soultions given here?

Comment: Your's is error prone whenever `i` is used after the function call, that's why I gave a critique.

Comment: The author wrote "I want to function fbreak break for loop. But it seems that my code does not work". Does he wrote that the value of i should remain same?

Comment: They didn't, but that doesn't make your recommendation better. I would avoid doing such like hell!

Comment: Well, downvoting my answer as a _revenge_ in turn, doesn't make yours better. Neither it is correct behavior for SO.